# In excel returning whole column in the middle of a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am currently using an index/match formula in Excel

```
=index(P:P,Match(1,B:B="text")*(F:F="text2"),0))
```

Instead of knowing in advance that the data is in column `P:P`, can this be set up so the formula will find the right column from its heading? For example, finding that the column that is named SAMPLES that is usually in column `P:P` had been shifted to column `Q:Q`, the formula would use `Q:Q` instead?

EDIT: I have made some progress, I now have 1 column being flexible with

```
   =index(A:Z,match(1,(B:B="text")*(F:F="text2"),0)match("samples",1:1,0))
```

Now how would I make columns B:B and F:F flexible know the column b will always be headed by "color" and column F by "type"

Comment: By referencing entire columns, that construction is rendered incredibly resource-heavy. Do you really have data extending all the way to row 1048576?

Comment: No, only approximately 10k rows. But it is highly variable.

Comment: But surely you can choose a smaller, though sufficient, upper bound? That formula is having to process more than two million cells, an astonishing amount for a single formula.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - it's the `Index-Match-Match` idiom.

```
=Index(LookupRange, Row, Column)
```

That's the full syntax of `Index`. In your formula, `Index` is looking at column P, `Match` is choosing the row, and you're not choosing a column so you're getting column P.

```
=Index(P:P, Match("text2", F:F, 0) )
```

You need to change P:P to refer to the whole sheet (or the parts of it that have data), and add a second `Match` to find the column:

```
=Index(A:Z, Match("text2", F:F, 0), Match("SAMPLES", 1:1, 0) )
       ^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I would actually need to match for every column, in my example P:P, B:B, and F:F, could you give me an example  of what the correct structure for that would be. Thanks